How to use ffmpeg to convert a flac file to alac and preserving all metadatas?
I use this loop to convert flac to alac :
for i in *.flac; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -y -vn -c:a alac "${i%.flac}".m4a; done
But some tags are not exported. I tried to use the -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 2 flag but it does not change anything.
Here you can find the tags that are copied (with or without the -map_metadata) :

original tags
tags copied

When I use XLD Mac software it works perfectly but for some reasons I'd like to use CLI to convert flac files.

Different file formats support different metadata fields. I'm not familiar with MP4 containers' capabilities though.

@DanielB is absolutely right.  The MP4 tags are different than ID3 tags, and there isn't always a direct translation between the two.

The relevant info is usually in the cuesheet.  Do you have the .cue file or only the files?  Run exiftool on a track and show the output.

Something you can do, to help ensure proper tagging, is the conversion separate from the tagging.
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.flac; do
    filename="${i%.*}"
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -an -f ffmetadata "$filename".id3
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -y -c:a alac -map_metadata -1 no_tag_"$filename".m4a
    ffmpeg -i no_tag_"$filename".m4a -c:a copy -i "$filename".id3 -map_metadata 1 -id3v2_version 3 "$filename".m4a
done

rm *.id3 no_tag_*

exit 0

Save: manual_tags.sh
Make executable: chmod +x manual_tags.sh
Usage: ./manual_tags.sh
